# Stream.Seek not supported on AssetManager.Open?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, filestream

I'm currently trying to port my Windows-based game to Android, and I'm getting stuck on getting the filesystem to load on mobile.

I store my files in an archive format of sorts, to avoid having to deal with different filesystems by just making my own instead. It, however, relies on FileStreams being able to seek to find the correct position of the data inside the archive.

According to [Microsoft's docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.content.res.access), both Access.Random and Access.Streaming should support seeking within the stream, but no matter what I do, a stream created using AssetManager.Open(string, Access) crashes when I call Stream.Seek from it, giving a NotSupportedException.

Is this a bug on my end, or a known defect on the SDK, and is there a workaround to it?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: As requested, a minimum reproducable example.

```
//class Game is a part of the MonoGame SDK. Game.Activity.Assets is a direct, unmodified version of
//Android.Content.Res.AssetManager, at least according to the docs.
//I believe the Seek function not being supported is a part of Xamarin's SDK, not Monogame's.
Stream stream = Game.Activity.Assets.Open(PathToArchive, Android.Content.Res.Access.Random);

stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); //causes exception regardless of seek value provided, and regardless of where the function is called.
```

Comment: We would love to see a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Yes,the stream from `Assets.Open()` does indeed not support `Seek` operations. You could verify this by looking at the `CanSeek` property.It will give you `false`.

So you could do like this:

```
Stream stream = Assets.Open(PathToArchive, Android.Content.Res.Access.Random);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
stream.CopyTo(ms);
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);//use ms in place of stream
```

Comment: Thank you. Curiously the answer you provided doesn't seem to work properly, and trying to read the stream now instead produces garbage data. That might be an actual bug, though.

Comment: @Catonator This solution is only for the stream seek operation,i do not know what file you need to operate, I use .txt file for testing and it works well.About the new issue,you could post a new question.

Comment: Whoops, I thought I had edited my comment! It's a custom binary file, so the behaviour might be different. I'm going to direct my questions to the Xamarin forums, since what's happening here doesn't sound intentional. Thanks for your time.